# Background Thread doesn't work, but with a simple 'System.out' works

Tags: java, multithreading

A strange thing. Code below works, if the condition `desiredHealth < p.getFakeHealth()` is true, it DOES SOMETHING.

```
     @Override
     public void run(){
        while(game_running){
            System.out.println("asd");
            if(desiredHealth < player.getFakeHealth()){
             DOES SOMETHING
          }
        }
```

BUT... without 'System.out' it does not work. It doesn't check the condition.
It is somehow on lower priority, or something.

```
     @Override
     public void run(){
        while(game_running){
            if(desiredHealth < player.getFakeHealth())
             DOES SOMETHING
          }
        }
```

I'm new to threads, so please, dont shout at me :)

Just for info, this thread is a normal class which 'extends Thread' and yes - it is running. Also 'game_running' is true all the time.

Comment: in second example the paranthesis are different

Comment: could you extend your code to show an example we can follow? How do you create the threads? How do you measure "does not work"? Have you debugged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the variable must be volatile because the volatile keyword indicates that a value may change between different accesses, even if it does not appear to be modified.

So, be sure `game_running` is declared `volatile`.

Comment: @Kuba The runtime and compiler are free to assume that your code follows the rules and break it horribly if you violate the rules. You are only guaranteed that one memory operation happens before another if you do something specific to guarantee it. You need the write to `desiredHealth` (and/or whatever `getFakeHealth` reads) to occur before the read, or the change won't be seen. What did you do to ensure that? (Search [this doc](https://www.cs.umd.edu/users/pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#synchronization) for "incorrectly synchronized". Your code probably qualifies.)

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation:**
Ahh, I have seen this on an older SO question. I'm gonna try to find it for further information.

Your problem is happening because the output stream's print is blocking the current thread and one of the `desiredHealth` and `player.getFakeHealth()` expressions get a second chance to be evaluated/changed by other thread and *voilà!* Magic happens. This is because `printf` on `glibc` is synchronized, so when you print, the rest of the operations are waiting for the `println` operation to complete.

**Resolution:**
We don't have enough context(who is initializing the player, who does the changes and so on), but it's obvious that you have a threading issue, something is not properly synchronized and your background thread works with bad values. One of the reasons might be that some variables are not `volatile` and if your background thread reads a cached value, you already have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

One of the topics you need to study regarding concurrency is the [Java memory model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) (that's the official spec but I suggest you read a tutorial or a good book, as the spec is rather complicated for beginners).

One of the issues when different threads work with the same memory (use the same variable - e.g. when one is writing into a variable, the other makes decisions based on their value) is that for optimization reasons, the values written by one thread are not always seen by the other.

For example, one thread could run on one CPU, and that variable is loaded into a register in that CPU. If it needed to write it back to main memory all the time, it would slow processing. So it manipulates it in that register, and only writes it back to memory when it's necessary. But what if another thread is expecting to see the values the first thread is writing?

In that case, it won't see them until they are written back, which may never happen.

There are several ways to ensure that write operations are "committed" to memory before another thread needs to use them. One is to use synchronization, another is to use the `volatile` keyword.

`System.out.println()` in fact includes a synchronized operation, so it may cause such variables to be committed to memory, and thus enable the thread to see the updated value.

Declaring the variable as `volatile` means that any changes in it are seen by all the other threads immediately. So using `volatile` variables is also a way of ensuring that they are seen.

The variable that is used to decide whether to keep the thread running should normally be declared `volatile`. But also, in your case, the variables `desiredHealth` (if it's written by a different thread) and whatever variables `getFakeHealth()` relies on (if they are written by a different thread) should be volatile or otherwise synchronized.

The bottom line is that whatever information is shared between two threads needs to be synchronized or at the very least use `volatile`. Information that is not shared can be left alone.